# Android studio waiting for emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I got a problem with **android studio**. I'm using **android studio 2.2.3**. I created an **AVD** of **nexus 5x** with latest Nougat image. When I'm trying to execute/run an application with emulator, though emulator is online the studio is giving message **"waiting for emulator to some online..."**. And it was stuck at this forever. Please help me out. And, if possible help me out in installing google play services on AVD.

Thankyou.

Comment: "help me out in installing google play services on AVD" -- You need to download the SDK image for the Google APIs. Alternatively, try using Genymotion. It's much quicker

Comment: Recreate your emulator or restart existing one. You can download the apks for google play services and install those in the emulator.

Comment: @PrashantSable I tried all possible ways like restarting or making studio to start emulator. But all in vain. And, if I'm trying to install an apk from outside it is throwing an error "invalid adb path" kind of. :(